# How to re-run local resolvers in React Apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

In my queries, I use a blend of remote and local properties, like this:

```
foo {
  bar
  baz
  qux @client
  quux @client {
    corge
    grault
  }
}
```

I have resolvers in place for `qux` and `quux`, but I'd like to recompute the data once every so often. I thought about writing directly to the cache with `cache.writeData` and `setInterval`, but that would a lot of rewriting.

Is there a way to run the resolvers again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to run the resolvers again on a specific interval, you can pass `pollInterval` as an option to your graphql HOC or as a prop to your Query component, depending on your implementation. Alternatively, if you would like to requery in response to, for example, a user event, you could invoke the `refetch` function, which should be accessible via props. For additional info see docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/essentials/queries/).

Comment: Many thanks. Is it possible to use `pollInterval` with Hooks?

Comment: **Update**: yes, it's just an [option](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#usequery) in the configuration object of `useQuery`.

Comment: But now the question is whether there's something I can do to not make a query again, but run the local resolvers?

Comment: @PaulBerg - Can you provide a little more detail as to how you're using the local resolvers? For example, are you writing any data to cache? You might be able to just set up another query `fooMini` that only invokes the local resolvers and just poll or refetch that.

Comment: I assembled a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-frost-6xotc) for you. See the `queries.js` file and notice the `paid @client` parameter in the `GET_STREAM` query. Unfortunately I don't think I can move the local state parameters to a different query, because they depend on the remote data.

Comment: Thanks for the sanbox. I'm working from the assumption your intent is to rerun those local resolvers without making another network call. I still think you could setup another query with just the local resolver(s).  In the local resolver, first run a check against the `obj` parameter, which it looks like you're deconstructing. If your remote data isn't there, read it from cache -- I believe we can assume this cached data is still good based on the info you've provided. Look at the method `readQuery` and be sure to pass correct variables. If the remote data is present on your `obj`, use that.